# XML validation fails for array type elements

Tags: xsd

I am trying to validate the schema for the element which occurs multiple (3) times in XML but schema validation is always fails giving the error "Schemas validity error : Element 'name': This element is not expected. "name" is an intermediate elements of XML file i.e. have other elements in XML file as well.

**Sample XML-**

```
<name>
  <A>1</A>
  <B>1</B>
</name>              
<name>
  <A>1</A>
  <B>1</B>
</name>
<name>
  <A>1</A>
  <B>1</B>
</name>
```

Please suggest sample schema to validate the XML element. I have tried lots of approaches given using `maxOccurs` but none is successfull.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like this is **all** you have in your .xml file. If so, I think the problem is that you need a root, in this example, I'll use   as an example, since I don't know exactly what you want to do with these elements. At the start of your file it is useful to put and "XML" declaration, ""

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<names>
   <name>
      <A>1</A>
      <B>1</B>
   </name>              
   <name>
      <A>1</A>
      <B>1</B>
   </name>
   <name>
      <A>1</A>
      <B>1</B>
   </name>
</names>
```

By the way, you might find this short introductory XML tutorial from IBM to be of some use:
<[IBM tutorial, in PDF format:](http://download.boulder.ibm.com/ibmdl/pub/software/dw/xml/x-newxml/x-newxml-pdf.pdf)>

I hope that helps.

Comment: hi , we already have the tags for the same in xml file
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=".xsd">
also we have prepared the schema as below-
         <xs:element name="name" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="3" >
            <xs:complexType mixed="true">
              <xs:sequence >
                <xs:element ref="A"/>
                <xs:element ref="B"/>
              <xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        
but doesnt work...

Comment: Hi, I'm new to XML myself, so that is why I pointed you to the introduction. I think you are beyond where I am at in this. But I'll try to do some research and see if I can find anything more out.

Comment: Hi, in your "xsd" file, I think you want "<xsd: schema xmlns:xsi= ...>", then you'll want to close your file with "</xsd: schema>"

Comment: Here is a question a lot like yours in SO: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542063/schema-validation-with-maxoccurs-element-fails>